# С++ в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Решил проверить код из книги ООП в С++ Лафоре но в Visual Studio не получается его повторить

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int Main()
{
    for (int j = 0; j<80; j++)
    {
        char ch = (j%8) ? ' ' : 'x';
        cout << ch;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

В Borland все работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как оно вообще скомпилировалось? С `Main` вместо `main`?

Comment: main с маленькой он бьет ошибку 

1>------ Сборка начата: проект: ConsoleApplication1, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: _main уже определен в ConsoleApplication1.obj
1>C:\My Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe : fatal error LNK1169: обнаружен многократно определенный символ - один или более
1>Сборка проекта "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========

Comment: Ну так а что такое `Source.cpp`, откуда он взялся, и что он делает у вас в проекте?

Answer (score 1):

Причина: функция `int main()` должна быть с маленькой буквы

Почему в данном файле он VS выдавал ошибку, если писать её с маленькой? Потому что точкой входа в программу в данном случае в VS является файл `*.cpp`, имя которого совпадает с именем проекта, то есть `ConsoleApplication1.cpp`. Именно там находится `int main()`, и оно уже было сгенерированно самой IDE, но вы видимо не увидели.

Таким образом, весь код надо поместить в `ConsoleApplication1.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам. причин не знаю но в новом проекте все заработло

Comment: Извините, но Вы не "разобрались", потому как "причин не знаю". Про main Вам написали выше. А вообще, в VS, насколько я помню, можно указать точку входа в настройках проекта.

Comment: согласен, от части вы правы, но если задача стояла "хочу что-бы все работало"  то самостоятельно положительного результата я добился)

и конечно спасибо за разъяснение проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю, откуда Вы брали тексты примеров, но если взять их с ОФЦИАЛЬНОГО сайта (в книжке есть ссылка) и скачать, то выглядит этот текст так:

```
 // condi.cpp // prints 'x' every 8 columns
 // demonstrates conditional  operator

 #include <iostream> using namespace std;

 int main()    {    for(int j=0; j<80; j++)
      //for every column,
       {                             //ch is 'x' if column is
       char ch = (j%8) ? ' ' : 'x';  //multiple of 8, and
       cout << ch;                   //' ' (space) otherwise
       }    return 0;    }
```

И всё великолепно компиллируется и работает.